# Transform Observable based on previous values

Tags: rxjs

- I have stream of events of 20 different types.
- I would like set a boolean for each event if an event of similar type was emitted within the last 10 seconds.
- This should happen live, I don't want to delay the events for 10 seconds.
- The event stream is continuous and does not end

Can this be done with RxJs?

**UPDATE:** Here is a JsBin demo of my event stream (Please take a look at the comments) http://jsbin.com/jepesu/1/edit?js,console,output

Comment: can you do a marble diagram to specify the behaviour you seek? i.e. what are your inputs, and expected outputs? Sample data which can be copy pasted would be optimal. In any case, the answer is probably yes.

Comment: I created a JsBin with a demo of my event stream and comments on what should happen next. Could you take a look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem. The events look like this:

```js
{
  id: 0,            // unique
  title: 'xxx',
  sound: 'p0',      // One of 'p0', 'p1', 'p2'
  playSound: false, // If the sound should be played
}
```

Sounds shall only be played if a sound of the same type wasn't played in the last 5 seconds. `playSound` is the boolean I want to toggle. For that I need a helper function: `throttleMap`

```js
/**
 * Executes a map function on the first element in the window, returns the rest as is
 * In other words: Executes mapFunction on all elements the Rx.throttle() function would
 * emit, emits all other elements unchanged
 */
Rx.Observable.prototype.throttleMap = function (windowDuration, mapFunction, scheduler) {
    Rx.Scheduler.isScheduler(scheduler) || (scheduler = Rx.Scheduler.default);
    var duration = +windowDuration || 0;
    if (duration <= 0) { throw new RangeError('windowDuration cannot be less or equal zero.'); }
    var source = this;
    return new Rx.AnonymousObservable(function (o) {
      var lastOnNext = 0;
      return source.subscribe(
        function (x) {
          var now = scheduler.now();
          if (lastOnNext === 0 || now - lastOnNext >= duration) {
            lastOnNext = now;
            o.onNext(mapFunction(x));
          }
          else {
            o.onNext(x);
          }
        },function (e) { o.onError(e); }, function () { o.onCompleted(); }
      );
    }, source);
  };
```

Now the solution:

```js
const groupedSoundStream = singleNotificationStream
  .groupBy(
    (x) => x.sound,
    (x) => x
  )
  .flatMap((x) => {
    return x.throttleMap(5000, (x) => {
      x.playSound = true
      return x
    })
  })

 groupedSoundStream
   .subscribe((x) => console.log(secSinceStart()+'s', x))
```

Some sample output:

```
0.3s { id: 0,  title: 'M#0',  sound: 'p2', playSound: true  }
0.6s { id: 1,  title: 'M#1',  sound: 'p1', playSound: true  }
0.9s { id: 2,  title: 'M#2',  sound: 'p1', playSound: false }
1.2s { id: 3,  title: 'M#3',  sound: 'p0', playSound: true  }
1.5s { id: 4,  title: 'M#4',  sound: 'p2', playSound: false }
1.8s { id: 5,  title: 'M#5',  sound: 'p0', playSound: false }
2.1s { id: 6,  title: 'M#6',  sound: 'p1', playSound: false }
2.4s { id: 7,  title: 'M#7',  sound: 'p2', playSound: false }
2.7s { id: 8,  title: 'M#8',  sound: 'p2', playSound: false }
3.1s { id: 9,  title: 'M#9',  sound: 'p1', playSound: false }
3.4s { id: 10, title: 'M#10', sound: 'p1', playSound: false }
3.7s { id: 11, title: 'M#11', sound: 'p1', playSound: false }
4s   { id: 12, title: 'M#12', sound: 'p2', playSound: false }
4.3s { id: 13, title: 'M#13', sound: 'p0', playSound: false }
4.6s { id: 14, title: 'M#14', sound: 'p2', playSound: false }
4.9s { id: 15, title: 'M#15', sound: 'p1', playSound: false }
5.2s { id: 16, title: 'M#16', sound: 'p2', playSound: false }
5.5s { id: 17, title: 'M#17', sound: 'p2', playSound: true  }
5.8s { id: 18, title: 'M#18', sound: 'p0', playSound: false }
6.1s { id: 19, title: 'M#19', sound: 'p2', playSound: false }
6.4s { id: 20, title: 'M#20', sound: 'p1', playSound: true  }
6.7s { id: 21, title: 'M#21', sound: 'p2', playSound: false }
7s   { id: 22, title: 'M#22', sound: 'p1', playSound: false }
```